# How to access _content from a api response in python

Tags: python, http, response, web.py

i am using web.py to call an api and authorize whether the token is right or not.
it returns a response , i need to access the _content variable inside the object. it returns the object of type `"<class 'requests.models.Response'>"` , how to access the _content inside the response.

Here is the code:

```
url = AuthURL['URL'] +"/GetSession/"+secToken+"/"+Domain
try:
   #assert isinstance(url, object)
    response = requests.get(url)
    print type(response)
    except URLError, err:
  logger.info("Authorization failed",err)
  return response
```

**Response**
[image]

Comment: I can see there is also `content` variable. What is wrong with it?

Comment: `response.authResult.content`

Comment: thanks ! it works ! i will remove this question or if you post as answer, i can upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with objects and to access object properties you need to use such notation:

`response.authResult.content`